# Do connectable webparts need to be in the same project?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I've found two tutorials that I'm looking at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx
- http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-connectable-web-parts-using.html

But both talk about having one project with two webparts.  Can I still communicate between webparts if they are in seperate projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have consumer and provider web part in different projects. Even SharePoint has connectable web parts in different assemblies.

Check this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/ConnectingCustomWebParts.aspx

Comment: I think its worth pointing out that while you may be able to create consumer and provider Web parts in different projects, support for Web Part connections in SharePoint 2010 is "based on connecting Web Part instances that are running on the same Web Part page" (from the book "Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010").

Comment: That's a good reminder..technically those interfaces exchange data as part of web part and page life cycle so they should be on same page.