# Connected Webparts using the same Interface but different vs-solutions

Tags: connected-web-parts

I built a sample containing two webparts(provider and consumer) in one vs-solution and it works great. So technicaly I know how connected webparts work.

I want to develop a provider webpart that passes a simple string via an interface to
several other webparts.

In this post
[Do connectable webparts need to be in the same project?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14245/do-connectable-webparts-need-to-be-in-the-same-project)
I read that my webparts don't need to be in the same project, but they are in one single solution.

Because I need to get my already developed webparts working with the "new" provider I can't add them to a single solution.

Here's my question:

How can I access/provide an Interface for multiple webparts in different vs-solutions?

What I tried already is to add a copy of my Iinterface.cs to my existing solutions and work work with this one, but my webparts can't find possible connections to each other after deploying them.

Thanks a lot
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of trial and error I fount a solution.

I created a new vs-solution that only includes my interface.cs and deployed it to GAC.

I referenced this dll from the gac using the absolute path to it in my other solutions and now it's working well.